# Suggestions on how to split a slightly more complicated string using regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

Before I get any down votes please help me with the logic because I can't think of how to split this string properly. I can split strings but Regular Expressions doesn't seem to work as I expected. Any suggestions are appreciated.
Examples of strings:
1. Lg=0.3 µm,Wg=10 µm,M=1
2. Lg=10 µm²,Wg=10 µm,M=1

Currently I used this method:

```
public static string[] Quantity(string word)
        {
            string[] XtractedWord;
            Regex separators = new Regex(@"=([\d]+[.][\d]+|[\d]+)[/.A-Za-zµ\xB2\xB3]*[,]*");
            word = word.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
            XtractedWord = separators.Split(word);
            return XtractedWord;
        }
```

However, it returns 7 strings,
 "Lg", "10", "Wg", "10", "M", "1", "".
I want to split it to return only "Lg", "Wg", "M".
Please help me and Thank You in advance.
And please let me know the reasons for downvoting as I am still new.

Comment: Why not split on '='? and take split[0].

Comment: splitting on '=' gives "Lg", "0.3 µm,Wg" and so on which is already incorrect.

Comment: `Regex.Matches(word, @"\w+(?==)")`

Comment: I thought it was complicated, turns out its a lot simplier. Thanks a lot for your help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why regex?

```
public static string[] ExtractWords(string sentence)
{
    string[] extractedWords;
    string[] pieces = sentence.Replace(" ", "").Split(',');
    extractedWords = pieces.Select(str => str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf('='))).ToArray();

    return extractedWords;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer. Is it possible to return results in the form of an array of String? But of course it works as I want already. Thank You very much. I thought that regular expressions works better in this case turns out it does not.

Comment: Switch `ToList()` to `ToArray()`. Just that simple. And you can test if it performs faster once you found the correct regex for your requirement. I'm not a fan of regex cause it's hard to understand Intuitively.

Comment: I am new to C# so i easily get confused with Linq sometimes and am not soo familiar with ToList, so I apologize first. Lambda Expression is also new to me and that's why I need to learn about these functions you used. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: By the way, don't take the downvote too hard. Sometimes people judge your question because your question is not likely to benefit others or they think it's easy and you didn't put enough effort. My first answer received -3 in the first month and now the same answer is +6. Just keep yourself on track and do your best.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your encouragement.